# Blank page for edit.php

Tags: wp-admin, memory

I get a blank page on /wp-admin/edit.php after change the number of post to display.
The bug is due to the PHP memory, but on my hosting I have no possibility to change this value.

[image]

How to reset the number of post to display on the edit.php page please.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your usermeta database table, there will be rows containing a meta_key of `edit_post_per_page` find the row that matches your username and then either change the value to something more sensible, or delete that row to restore the default of 20. Or you could delete all rows in that table with that key, it's not a critical value and it will not break anything if removed.

[image]

Then I would take a look at your plugins to see which ones are consuming the most memory. There are plenty of free profiler plugins out there, I suggest you try a variety of them ( but not all at the same time )

Answer (score 0):

You can also try increasing your memory limit by editing your `wp-config.php` file and adding this to it: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

Comment: I tried this but my hosting is too basic