# Blank page after changing number of post displayed in wp-admin

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I have recently changed the number of posts displayed in the wp-panel (from 20 to 999).

My surprise is that after the changing, when trying to see the posts a blank page appears.

How can I come back to see the posts (20 for instance)?

Comment: Can you check PHP error log? It's possible that your server doesn't have enough memory allocated to PHP. Showing 999 posts at once needs a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't know where to find that PHP error log. Furthermore, I found this question (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48150/blank-page-for-edit-php), but I don't know either where to find the usermeta database table. Do you mind telling me where can I find them?

Comment: If your hosting provides `CPanel`, then you'll find a tool called `PHPMyAdmin` there, you'll find the database table using `PHPMyAdmin`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (almost) your php resources are being exhausted because of 999 requests. Log in to your host, and look for your panel. Once you are in administration panel, you should be able to find `PHPMyAdmin` without a problem. Otherwise, you can download and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reset "Post_Per_Page" field, please refer attached screenshot, you need to update "Blog pages show at most" file and you can find it at Admin >> Settings >> Reading.

If you are unable to access admin area as well, you can change it directly in database.
To change this variable directly in database open "wp_options" table, search for record where "option_name" = 'posts_per_page' and update "option_value" column for that record.

[image]
Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is the number of posts to be displayed in the blog/webpage, but not the posts that are displayed in the Post tab of the wp-admin. Thanks anyway!